# Firebase auto SMS retrieval not working in firebase auth

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I implemented the latest version of firebase authenticatin in my android app. In this version firebase auto SMS retrieval is not working like previous versions I want to retrieve SMS if the SIM is present in same phone.

I implented braodcast receiver but it is not working because of message format

How can I acheive auto SMS retrieval in android app? Is there any code implementation in the code or is there any additional code that can be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue introduced in latest firebase libraries.

It works till firebase BOM 25.11.0 and post that it is not at all working. I have tried many intermediate BOMs until 29.0.0 and no where it is working. I am not able to upgrade to latest version of firebase BOM because of this issue. Now I am forced to upgrade as I was getting runtime error related to OkHttp.

I have raised this issue some 3-4 months back. It seems it is not at all addressed. I am surprised to see how other

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30239474)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone), this method of authentication has auto retrieval

> Google Play services can automatically
> //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
> //     user action.

You can look up if your google play service is up to date. I have used this auth several times and the SMS is automatically retrieved by google play services without any additional code

Comment: It is not working in 20.0.0 dependency i checked it